# Do Real Values sort different than floats in SQL Server queries?

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone think of a reason to do this:

SELECT * FROM TableA
ORDER BY cast(cast(RealColumnA as nvarchar(50))as float)
--where RealColumnA is defined as real in the table

A former developer of mine insisted this was necessary to get reals to sort correctly.  Can anyone think of a reason that may be true?

The cast in the orderby clause is a big performance killer.  But I need to be sure it is not necessary before I remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove it. ORDER BY is what you expect it to be. And it certainly would be a performance killer.

Rule #1 about SQL. Question (and test) all your (and other peoples') assumptions. (Especially weird ones like this.)

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense.  Especially with the `CAST` right back.

The only thing I could see is if you are storing non-`float` information in a `float` and want it sorted asciibetically.  I guess you might want this:

```
1
10
11
12
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

But usually when that kind of storage optimization is done (like SSN or a phone number stored in an int, say), there is implicit padding assumed on the left which means that any expected sort is really the same as the normal numerical sort.